# JQuery mobile & phonegap = no landscape rotation?

Tags: iphone, jquery-mobile, cordova

I'm writing an iPhone app using jQuery mobile & phonegap. When I rotate my iPhone into landscape orientation, nothing happens. Clearly I'm missing something! Anyone more clever than I able to tell me what?!

Comment: I think this question might help: [3547860](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3547860/)

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7003533/jquery-mobile-orientation-detection

Comment: Might need per window.shouldRotateToOrientation = ... per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10999435/why-doesnt-my-cordova-phonegap-ios-app-rotate-when-the-device-rotates/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you set up landscape as a supported device orientation?

You can do this by showing the project navigator and clicking on your project, then selecting the relevant target. Under the "Summary" tab, look for "Supported Device Orientations" and make sure "Landscape Left" and "Landscape Right" have the pressed-in effect.

If they're both enabled, make sure this line is in your header:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0;" />
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Hi Zumi, cheers for this. It makes sense it's an Xcode issue, I wasn't sure where to pin the blame before! It's odd, but in Xcode 4.2 I can't find a 'Summary' tab in any view... I've checked all the tabs and I've searched help for 'Device Orientations', to no avail. I fear I'm yet again being stupid as hell! Any advice?

Comment: Hi Richard. Sorry for being so long to respond. If you've found an answer, then that's great! If not, then here we go:  

* On the left side of the screen, you'll see a sidebar. At the top of this are 7 grey icons. Make sure the folder (project navigator) is selected.  
* In this list, you'll see your project. It's got a blue "A" icon next to it. Click your project.  
* A new sidebar next to your left sidebar will appear. It'll have "Project," then "Targets." Select your project.  
* At the top of the main screen here are five tabs, the first of which is "Summary."    

Good luck!

Comment: `user-scalable=no` is simpler than `initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0`

Answer (score 0):

On iOS 6 you need to add the following in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions to respond to orientation changes:

```
 self.window.rootViewController = viewController;
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone using Phonegap Build and version 2.0.0, the solution may just be to change up to version 2.1.0 by amending your config.xml file.