# jquery mobile orientation detection

Tags: jquery-mobile, ios-simulator, orientation, browser-detection, jammit

I am using jquery-mobile and it seems it doesn't detect the landscape setting. What I am using:

iphone simulator Version 4.3 (238.2) from Xcode Version 4.1 Build 4B110
   jquery mobile

I tried to do this in my mobile.js

```
$(window).bind('orientationchange resize', function(event){
  alert(event.orientation)
})
```

and turning the simulator around just keeps giving me an alert that says "portrait" when it clearly should be landscape.

am i doing something wrong here? I also tried using media queries in our jammit call:

```
<%= include_stylesheet :landscape, :media => "all and (orientation: landscape)" %>
```

but to no avail. AM i doing something wrong here?

The main bug btw is that even when turning the iphone, the display still stays at portrait width for us.

Comment: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0b2/#/demos/1.0b2/docs/api/mediahelpers.html Note: This feature is deprecated in beta, and will be removed after that. We recommend using CSS3 Media Queries instead.

Comment: in the last part of my question i DID try the css3 media queries(which also didn't work for me...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this in the jQM b2 js file:

- http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0b2/jquery.mobile-1.0b2.js

JS:

```
alert('Orientation: ' + jQuery.event.special.orientationchange.orientation());
```

Here is the function itself:

```
// Get the current page orientation. This method is exposed publicly, should it
// be needed, as jQuery.event.special.orientationchange.orientation()
$.event.special.orientationchange.orientation = get_orientation = function() {
    var elem = document.documentElement;
    return elem && elem.clientWidth / elem.clientHeight < 1.1 ? "portrait" : "landscape";
};
```