# Working with orientation of the iPad in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, cordova

I am working with the orientation in iPad . I am using phone gap for building the application. 
I have done following code for orientation change :

```
       function updateOrientation() 
        {
            var orientation=window.orientation;
            if ( orientation == 0 ) {
                alert("Do Something In Portrait Mode");
            }
            else if ( orientation == 90 ) {
                alert("Do Something In landscape Mode");
            }
            else if ( orientation == -90 ) {
                alert("Do Something In Portrait Mode");
            }
            else if ( orientation == 180 ) {
                alert("Do Something In landscape Mode");
            }               
        }
```

I am getting the alerts but I don't know how to resize the window inside this ? Can anybody help me ?I want like following :
[image]

Comment: Have you considered using libs like jQuery Mobile? :S It can make things easier I guess...

Comment: No can you please give some more information.]

Comment: jQuery Mobile is a javascript lib which helps you create web app for mobiles. It provides native-like components and has a special design which adapts according to the device's orientation. You may have a look at it: http://jquerymobile.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both Safari and Android support a simple orientation change event listener.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=320; user-scalable=no" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>PhoneGap</title>
     <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="phonegap-1.1.0.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="main.js"></script>

</head>
<body onload="init();" >

    <h2>Orientation Test</h2>
    <div id="status"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

And js code :

```
function init() {
    window.addEventListener("orientationchange", orientationChange, true);
}

function orientationChange(e) {
    var orientation="portrait";
    if(window.orientation == -90 || window.orientation == 90) orientation = "landscape";
        document.getElementById("status").innerHTML+=orientation+"<br>";
}
```

[Source](http://www.raymondcamden.com/index.cfm/2011/11/4/PhoneGap-Orientation-Example)